# How to go to the app store (from within app) programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, app-store

After clicking on a UIView I want to take the user of my app OUT of my app and to another app on the app store. How do i do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NSString *buyString=@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=APP_ID&mt=8";

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:buyString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

Comment: this is not valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"APP_STORE_URL_OF_EXISTING_APP"]
```

This will automatically quit your application and launch App Store application.

Answer (score 0):

Modernising in Objective-C

```
NSString *appString = @"https://apps.apple.com/app/app-name/app-id";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url
                                   options:@{}
                         completionHandler:nil];
```